# Refreshing leadbolt html banner ads

Tags: jquery, cordova, ads, leadbolt

How can i refresh leadbolt html banner ads ie. to show a different ad after some few seconds. I tried using jquery load and setInterval methods which only outputs random texts.

Comment: You need to expand your question please. How is the banner ad displayed? How is the ad requested?

Comment: @darryn.ten: The question already have clear meaning. Perhaps you don't read the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard HTML banner in phonegap then rotating banners could be problematic.

You can use the phonegap compatibility library available in the LeadBolt publisher portal help/FAQ section, which will allow you to use LeadBolt’s advanced ad units and also allow you to call the below function on a timer to rotate banners (full documentation available in this section).

```
window.plugins.leadbolt.load(["MY_LEADBOLT_SECTION_ID", "appad", true], null, null);
```